# Are class usage statistics available?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, class, pathfinder-society

Paizo knows about every game my characters play in the Pathfinder Society, and their class. Is there some public information somewhere about these?

A naïve google search did not find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Probably Not

Class isn't a required field for characters on Paizo's website. Any data they do have is a partial list, and could be incorrect if a character was rebuilt and the character info not updated.

### However

I have a personal list of characters I've played with or GMed for in Pathfinder Society. It's unique by character name. Here's the summary table:

| Class | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Fighter | 46 |
| Rogue | 44 |
| Cleric | 42 |
| Magus | 41 |
| Ranger | 39 |
| Sorcerer | 39 |
| Champion | 31 |
| Barbarian | 30 |
| Monk | 30 |
| Wizard | 28 |
| Bard | 26 |
| Gunslinger | 25 |
| Summoner | 25 |
| Inventor | 23 |
| Swashbuckler | 23 |
| Druid | 22 |
| Alchemist | 21 |
| Oracle | 17 |
| Investigator | 14 |
| Thaumaturge | 10 |
| Witch | 8 |
| Psychic | 7 |

**Total**: 591

Caveats:

1. The total is relatively small. I'd be more confident in the data with 1000+.
2. Dark Archive was released fairly recently, Thaumaturge & Psychic haven't been out for long enough to accurately compare with the other classes.
3. The random-party nature of Pathfinder Society may skew the numbers in favor of certain classes that are more self-sufficient and/or more likely to work well with others.
4. This is a personal list from my own online play. It may not be indicative of the whole of Pathfinder Society.

If anyone else has their own personal list they could theoretically be combined to get a more accurate picture, assuming duplicates can be removed.

Comment: See [this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12277/62294), your table didn't render properly in the first revision.

Comment: Surprisingly high amount of maguses

Comment: could I have the anonymized data?

Comment: Out of curiosity, ,were there no people playing multiple classes?  Or if there were, how did you account for them in your data?

Comment: @Alan PF2e doesn't allow you to take levels in different classes like PF1e. Multiclassing is done by taking Dedication feats that give you access to specific class abilities.

Comment: @András Here's what I've got with identifying information removed. I recorded subclass for some of the characters but not all. I'd recommend making a copy as I'll probably delete the sheet eventually https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FA0VYcnEnW1N94afKYOd3v8Mduo6u1BYnHD_cgRR2VQ/

Comment: @WeirdFrog Thanks for the data.

Comment: Fighters have a reputation among hardcore PF2 nerds as being "S Tier" (although most will also admit classes are relatively well balanced compared to most D&D versions). This surprises a lot of neophytes though, particularly if they have 5E experience. Witch similarly hits the bottom of many such lists, as do Alchemist, Oracle, and Investigator.

Comment: @T.E.D. I can't speak for everyone, but many of the people I've played with in PFS aren't interested in building the best character possible, they want to build something competent and fun. Witch is at the bottom of the list because it has fewer spell slots than Sorcerer and gets very little in return, and running out of spell slots is no fun. Fighter is an excellent platform to expand many character concepts, they're pretty boring to start, but archetypes and their wide range of feats make them more versatile and interesting.

Comment: @WeirdFrog - Same. My home table has none of the top 4 classes, and a Witch. But the question and the answer were about Pathfinder Society, which I think we can assume is generally made up of rather more hardcore players than the average table, and are going to be a bit more interested in min-maxing.

Comment: My wife btw is playing the Witch, and its being plenty fun for her. Perhaps helps that she's the only spellcaster main in the group, but everyone appreciates the hell out of that pinch upcasted AoE heal, and she's really leaned into making potions with the cauldron.